# KafkaConsumer never exits .poll method - GroupCoordinatorNotAvailableException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have an implementation of a `KafkaConsumer` in java, and currently it is never exiting the `.poll` method. When I drill down into the source code in debug mode I've found that it is getting stuck in the while loop in `AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorKnown()`, as the coordinator is never found.

The future returned from `sendGroupMetadataRequest()` in the loop fails the first time with `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SendFailedException`, and then will fail every subsequent time with `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupCoordinatorNotAvailableException: The group coordinator is not available.`. Does anyone know why this might happen?

If I use the console producer/consumer I am able to successfully send and receive messages, it is only when I use my implementation of the KafkaConsumer. Additionally, the consumer does work on two of my servers so I know it is not the implementation of the consumer.

Here are the properties my consumer is created with:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "myserver:9000);
props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("group.id", groupId);
props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
```

**Edit:**

The topic is definitely created before the consumer starts.

**Edit 2:**
I deleted all of the brokers in my cluster and recreated them, and now I'm failing at a different point. In `AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup()` while trying to rejoin, the future returned from `performGroupJoin()` repeatedly fails with `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotCoordinatorForGroupException: This is not the correct coordinator for this group.`. Still not sure what is going on.

**Edit 3:**
I deleted the brokers and recreated them with a different id and now the `.poll()` method is returning and it's successfully consuming messages. I'd still like to know why it failed in the first place though so I can make sure it doesn't happen again.

Comment: Which version of Kafka? same version for brokers and consumers? Is Kafka really listening on myserver:9000 (9092 is default)? Can you connect from consumer machine to Kafka via telnet?

Comment: I'm using Kafka 0.9.1. Yes kafka is really listening there, I use the same broker for the console consumer I created as the java one. Just googled telnet and I have no idea if it's running on the server. What would connecting to it prove when I already know I can consume from the console consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the brokers and creating new ones fixed the problem. Still not sure went wrong with the brokers though.